Hitting time and first hitting time
The following statement is in fact a middle step that I want to prove when I try to show that the probability of the first hitting time of symmetric random walk in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ equals $t$ is smaller than that in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for all $t$.
Let $X=\{X_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty},Y=\{Y_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be two real-valued stochastic process defined on the same probability space. $X_0=Y_0=0$. Define the first hitting as
$$
\tau_x=\inf_{n>0} \{n:X_n=0\},\tau_y=\inf_{n>0} \{n:Y_n=0\}
$$
If $P(X_n=0)\le P(Y_n=0)$ for all $n$, can we show that $P(\tau_x=n)\le P(\tau_y=n)$?
I think it's intuitively right and I hope someone could give a hint. Thank you very much.

No, this is not true.  Let $Y_n = 0$ for all $n$ and $X$ be a simple random walk.  Then $P(Y_n = 0) = 1 \ge P(X_n = 0)$ for all $n$, but $\tau_y = 1$ so $P(\tau_y = n) = 0$ for all $n > 1$.  Since $P(\tau_x = 2) > 0$, we don't have $P(\tau_x = n) \le P(\tau_y = n)$ for all $n$.

Your're right. I wonder if it is true that $P(\tau_x <\infty) \le P(\tau_y <\infty)$ given the same condition.
